# How to move all old files from Downloads to the trash with one or more terminal commands in macos?

Tags: macos, command-line, grep, find, trash

I already found the command with which I can select all the files and directories that I do **not** want to send to trash. That command looks like this:

`find ~/Downloads -newerat "2 months ago" -or -newerct "2 months ago" -or -newermt "2 months ago" | grep -E "^$HOME/Downloads/[^/]+$"`

So the `find` part of the command selects every file and folder which has either been added, created, or modified in the last two months. And then the `grep` portion of the command filters the list so that it only contains the top-level files and folders.

So that means for example that:

```
~/Downloads/SomeMovie/SomeMovie.mp4
~/Downloads/SomeMovie/SomeMovie.srt
```

Will just be filtered down to:

```
~/Downloads/SomeMovie
```

Now again, this is the list of files and folders I **do not** want to send to trash. For some reason I found this query easier to compute in my head. Now I'm wondering how I can best get the inverse of this list?

And by the inverse of this list I mean, if `find` starts selecting files and folders that have *not* been added, created, or modified in the last two months, I want to make sure that if any sub-tree contains even just *one* file that *was* added, created, or modified in the last two months, that then that entire sub-tree will be excluded from the search results.

You know what I mean? That's the part that I didn't know how to express that in a query.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446767/how-to-move-all-old-files-from-downloads-to-the-trash-with-one-or-more-terminal

Comment: If your algorithm working correctly for all the files and folders that you want to keep, just use it to move them all into a different location like a new folder in your home directory. Then just delete everything that is left in your downloads folder. Finally, move that “keep” folder from your home directory back into your downloads folder.

Comment: @jimtut that actually sounds like a very reasonable idea. It's simple and therefor unlikely to contain a mistake. The only thing I'm just a little worried about is that my Downloads folder is actually a symbolic link to a Downloads folder in my iCloud. So if I move files out of the folder and then move them back in 2 seconds later, won't iCloud think it needs to re-sync all of those files again?

Comment: Quite likely. I’d turn off your Wi-Fi/Ethernet while doing it, and iCloud should be smart enough to not delete then re-upload those files when the network comes back.